# Import GTFS realtime file into R

Tags: r, protocol-buffers, real-time, gtfs

I'm trying to import a GTFS realtime data [file](https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/) into R using the [ProtoBuf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RProtoBuf/vignettes/RProtoBuf-intro.pdf) package, but can't get it to work. This is what I've tried, but I think it's way off track.

```
library(RProtoBuf)

setwd("c:\\temp\\")
proto <- readProtoFiles("seq")
```

The `gtfsway` package reads the data from the site, like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132693/reading-gtfs-realtime-files-using-r), but the authors say the package is outdated.

Comment: It's not necessarily 'outdated', I just haven't maintained it in a while. I just ran the code in the question you link to and it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I get many warnings and then a message saying the load failed.

Comment: ok - If the package is causing issues please report the errors on the [issues page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/gtfsway/issues)

Comment: that link is for your package, not RProtoBuf

Comment: sorry, I thought you were saying my package is causing you issues.

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43746520/5977215) is also related

Comment: Thanks I'll work through it. I sent an email to your company info address.